# Can someone help me figure out to write this while loop?

Tags: java, input, while-loop, double, sentinel

I am really struggling to understand how to write this while loop based on the instructions. Can someone please show me what to do? I already tried to write my own code below and it's bad.

**Here are the instructions:**

Write a sentinel controlled while loop that will allow you to calculate the average low temperature for any month.  The average temperature should be displayed as a properly calculated double value. Explain why you chose the sentinel value.  The code for the input of the initial temperature value is provided.

**Here is my code:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int temp = scan.nextInt();

while ()
{
    temp = 5.0/9.0 * (temp - 32.0);
    System.out.println()
}
```

Comment: To start, do you understand what the question is asking? Or are you more having trouble converting your plan into code? What do you think the sentinel should be?

Comment: I am having trouble converting the plan into code and I think that the sentinel value should be a print statement value with user input.

Comment: A sentinel value usually refers to a variable that controls the loop's execution - e.g. a counter or a boolean that tells the loop when to stop. Based on the problem statement, it seems like it should be something that indicates that the user is done providing inputs.

Comment: So how do I write it?

Comment: The problem is leaving that up to you. What do you think it should be? Common examples I've seen include having the user specify the number of inputs they want to provide, or prompting for more inputs until the user enters a specific keyword (e.g., "quit").

Comment: Can you please just show me how to do it? I'm really stressed and this is due today.

Comment: As a general rule, Stack Overflow is not a homework-writing service. We can provide you with pointers and tips, not outright answers.

Comment: adding to the hints @Welbog has given ... ```scan.hasNext()``` will tell if the user has provided more inputs or not. u can keep it inside the while condition.

Comment: @AudreyWashington-Wright - Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518114/how-do-you-set-up-an-infinite-loop-in-scanners/64518701#64518701 for an example. You can find hundreds of such examples on SO.

Comment: None of this helps. I don't know what to do and I really need an answer.

Comment: If I were you I will do a looping --- ask the user to input the temperature, put them into array (or just the total sum and the count will also be sufficient) and calculate the average, then display the average (in double precision floating value)  until the user enters a negative number . The reason is that the temperature will never be a negative value

Answer (score 0):

The sentinel is any non-numeric string:

```
public class Sentinel {

    public static void main(String args []) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp = scan.next();
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;
        while (isNumeric(temp))
        {
            total += Double.parseDouble(temp);
            count++;
            temp = scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(total/count).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
    }
}
```

Your original code is also trying to convert from fahrenheit to celsius even though the problem statement doesn't say anything about the scale.

Comment: Your regex will fail to handle numbers like `double d = 123_234`.

Comment: I just need to see what to do.

Comment: Yeah, valid point @Arvind. I was going to use Apache to validate like I would if doing this for real, but was trying to save OP the hassle of using libraries. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

````
int n = scan.nextInt();           //to input number of days in a given month
int[] temp = new int[n];          //an array to store the low temps of all days
int i=0, total=0;
double avg=0.0;
while (i<n)
{   
    temp[i] = scan.nextInt();     //input temperature per day one at a time
    total=total+temp[i];          //to get the sum total of all days of the month
    i++                           //increment the counter i
}
avg=total/n;
System.out.println("the average low temperature is :"+avg);```
````

Comment: its just the function, create a class and import scanner before starting.